# Braintree for flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, braintree

I have a broader question. Is there any possibility to use a brain tree for the flutter web? I was searching for an API on pub.dev but there was only one for Android & Ios, but not for Web.

If there is one do you have a link to an example project, I just don't seem to find anything about the detailed integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Braintree using API calls with their GraphQL client. Read the whole guide on how to make API calls on their website.
[Making API Calls](https://graphql.braintreepayments.com/guides/making_api_calls/)